# Como eliminar todas las coincidencias?

Tags: javascript

```js
var b = "Holaa Holaa Holaa Holaa ";
console.log(b);
```

Como puedo eliminar todas las coincidencias de Holaa, excepto la primera?

Exactamente me refiero a toda la cadena en sí , tomando en cuenta este ejemplo:

```js
String.prototype.repetir = function(v) {
  
  return v < 1 ? '' : new Array(v+1).join(this);
  
};

var b = "hola pepe !".repetir(4);

console.log(b);
```

Básicamente como hacer la forma recursiva de la función repetir, eliminando todas las coincidencias de la oración entera, no solo palabras, pero como si no supieramos que existe esa función repetir.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var texto = "Holaa Holaa Holaa Adios Pedro Holaa";
var res = texto.split(" ");

arr = res.filter( function( item, index, inputArray ) {
           return inputArray.indexOf(item) == index;
    });

alert(arr);
```

Primero pasalo a un array (`.split()`), y luego filtralo (`.filter()`)

```js
var texto = "Holaa Holaa Holaa";
var res = texto.split(" ");

arr = res.filter( function( item, index, inputArray ) {
           return inputArray.indexOf(item) == index;
    });

alert(arr);
```

Comment: En esa solución el problema es que si el array contiene otras cosas también las elminaría, no? Saludos!!

Comment: He introducido otro código con mas cosas en el texto, para que veas que no las elimina.

Comment: Genial, siempre pensaba que el .filter lo que hacía era devolver sólo las coincidencias pero creo que eso es con algún modificador, no? Tome usted su voto positivo buen hombre. Saludos!!

Comment: El problema de esta solución es que elimina todas las palabras repetidas. No únicamente la que se busca. Aunque es una buena aproximación. Bastaría con cambiar la condición del filtro para que funcione correctamente.

Comment: Si es esta la respuesta apta, marca el tick ;P

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, prueba esto:

```js
s = 'Holaa Holaa Holaa Holaa ';
s = s.replace(/(?!^)Holaa/g, '');
alert(s);
```

Comment: me funciona, pero me gustaría si me lo explicas

Comment: El problema es que esta solución únicamente va a funcionar si el primer `Holaa` coincide con el principio de la cadena. No sé si es lo que se busca

Comment: Es una expresión regular que empieza después de la primera posición, por lo tanto reemplaza todas las "Holaa" por vacío.

Comment: @AsierVillanueva Así es, elimina las coincidencias menos la primera siempre y cuando esa palabra esté la primera (es lo que entendí), si no es así habría que realizar una función algo más compleja.

Comment: ok pero también me serviria para 'hola pedro hola pedro hola pedro' ? y dejar solo una vez el 'hola pedro'

Comment: no me sirve solo me elimina los hola

Comment: Si quieres que te elimine todas! las coincidencias la que te he colocado yo, si solo quieres que te elimine cierta palabra la que ha puesto @Hector.

Comment: @EduardoSebastian creo que deberías explicar mejor la pregunta. ¿Qué casos debe cubrir? ¿Qué tipo de cadenas de entrada puede tener? ¿Cómo se determina el texto a eliminar?

Comment: ya está @AsierVillanueva

Answer (score 0):

Con esto puedes solucionarlo facilmente y añadir al set solo una ocurrencia de cada una de las palabras que salgan en tu cadena.

Con el split separas la cadena por espacios en un array y vas añadiendo los elementos a un Set, que tiene la propiedad de que los elementos no se repiten en él.

```js
var b = "Holaa Holaa Holaa Holaa";
let mySet = new Set();
var array = b.split(" ");
for(let item of array){
  mySet.add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que estás buscando es un método que mire si una cadena es una repetición de otra cadena más pequeña y, en tal caso, extraer ésta:

```js
String.prototype.repetir = function(v) {  
  return v < 1 ? '' : new Array(v+1).join(this);
};

String.prototype.deshacerRepetir = function(){
  var re = /^(.+?)\1+$/;
  var match = re.exec(this);
  return match[match.length-1];
}

var b = "hola pepe !".repetir(4);

console.log(b.deshacerRepetir());
```